# postgresql group by column and select oldest date from each group

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to select a group, count the occurrences, and also return the oldest of the group. I was thinking along the lines of using a subquery with the immediate value, something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(submitdate), priority, 
 (SELECT submitdate FROM opentickets WHERE priority = priority ORDER BY submitdate ASC LIMIT 1) 
FROM opentickets
 WHERE assignee IS NULL
  GROUP BY priority
```

But I get the same date for all priority groups. Does anyone know if its possible to use a column value like this? For instance, " priority = priority " becomes " priority = 'P1' " then 'P2', 'P3' and so on.

Desired Output

```
count  priority   submitdate
  12     P1       "2017-04-03 10:48:14"
 152     P2       "2017-03-23 02:24:07"
 308     P3       "2017-03-03 05:06:43"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use max**

```
SELECT COUNT(submitdate), priority, 
max(submitdate)
FROM opentickets
WHERE assignee IS NULL
GROUP BY priority
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table test(priority varchar(10), submitdate timestamp);
> insert into test values
> ('P1', '20170101'),
> ('P1', '20170102'),
> ('P1', '20170103'),
> ('P2', '20170301'),
> ('P2', '20170501'),
> ('P3', '20170501'),
> ('P3', '20170601'),
> ('P3', '20170705');
>
> select     priority, 
>            count(submitdate) as count_dates,
>            max(submitdate) as max_date
> from       test
> group by   priority;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 8 rows affected
>
> priority | count_dates | max_date           
> :------- | ----------: | :------------------
> P2       |           2 | 2017-05-01 00:00:00
> P3       |           3 | 2017-07-05 00:00:00
> P1       |           3 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=abe9930244f20326d4f40c85cebd66e7)*